# attempt to change ec2 instance type fails instance status check

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2

So I have a micro instance for my new pet project [www.tryperl.com](http://www.tryperl.com). The micro instance is maxed out and I decided to change it to small.

I followed the accepted answer here on this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5898308/how-to-safely-upgrade-an-amazon-ec2-instance-from-t1-micro-to-large). However, I cannot get it to work for the life of me!

- I created snapshot from my small inst volume.
- I created an AMI from the snapshot and launched a new small instance
- (My small inst is set in us-east-1b and my micro  in us-east-1c, does it make a diff?)
- The small instance starts and takes forever for status checks and then fails saying `Instance reachability check failed`.
  When I click view rules on my security group, it says `No rules were found in the associated security groups` ??! But I'm SURE the security group does have http@80 open!

I'm currently trying a reboot

---

> Should I just stop my micro instance and change it's type? Are there consequences ? I know I'll have down-time. How much downtime will occur??

---

> What else can I try?

Comment: What status checks are you referring to? Did you launch the new instance with the same security groups?

Comment: I tried with the same security group and then created a new security group and tried again. No luck. After it goes from pending to running, it `loading..` in the status checks column and then after a long time says `1/2 checks failed`. On the bottom of the dashboard I see `Status Checks => Instance Status Checks` And it says reachability problem, try rebooting .. (which I did)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All in all I just did the following:

- Right-Click on the instance

  - Instance Lifecycle > Stop
  - Waited for 10 mins
  - Instance Management > Change Instance Type > Changed to Small
  - Instance was back and **running** in 10-15 mins
  - The domain was giving a `could not find`  for a couple minutes.

So I had some unfortunate down-time and no dinner! Oh well!