# How to launch Micro EC2 instance from Small AMI

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-ami

I have an AMI I created on a small EC2 instance.  I've spent most of the night attempting to launch it on a Micro instance.  It continually fails the `Instance Status Checks.`  I'm attempting to launch the instance from the AWS web interface.

I finally gave up and launched it as a Small instance in just a couple minutes.  I then followed the instructions in [attempt to change ec2 instance type fails instance status check](https://serverfault.com/questions/477692/attempt-to-change-ec2-instance-type-fails-instance-status-check) and "converted" it to a Micro instance.  I now get the same failing behavior as before.  If I "Get System Log" it's totally empty.

I'm guessing it's because the AMI has `Architecture` set to i386.  IF that's the case, is there a way for me to create a new AMI and change that or do I have to start all over and re-install my stack on a new x86_64 instance and create a new AMI?

Comment: As far as I know there is no constraint on the architecture of micro instances.

Comment: That's what I thought too, but apparently there is something going on, thus the question...

Answer (score 0):

Micro instances are be EBS backed, they cannot be AMI backed.

```
  http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/faqs
```

Comment: The faq says nothing of the sort.  My AMI is a custom built AMI that is EBS based. I started on Micro instances and had no problems using a homegrown AMI that was based on a Micro instance. This is back when Small didn't support 64 bit, so going to small I had to create a new AMI that was 32 bit. Now I can't start on Micro with the AMI that I created on Small and I'm wondering if there is a way around that without having to recreate the entire AMI.